# Arduino serial monitor showing garbage when transmiting data

Tags: c++, arduino

I have an a arduino transmiter setup with the nFR24L01 transever. When I try to send data between a arduino mega and an arduino uno, the serial monitor shows garbage.

Here is my code:

Mega:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8); // CNS, CE

const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
}

void loop() {
  const char text[] = "Hello World, tw";
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
  delay(500);
  radio.write("what about this?",15);
  delay(500);
}
```

Uno:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CNS, CE
const byte address[6] = "00001";
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Hello to the world.");
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.startListening();
}
void loop() {
  //delay(1000);
  if (radio.available()) {
    char text[32] = "";
    radio.read(&text, 15);
    Serial.println(text);
  }
}
```

[My Scematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hOfu.png)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. Can you post a photo or schematic of your setup?

Comment: I added a schematic to the post. Hope that helps.

Comment: The transmition is working fine. The serial monitor is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably the serial monitor is at a different buad rate than the code and/or the transceiver.

Try checking the serial monitor for the baud rate and set it to 9600.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me allot